# Getting the "ORA-00911" error when I am trying to insert more than 1 row

Tags: oracle-10g, insert

Lets say I have the follow insert statements.

```
INSERT INTO E_PRODUCT VALUES ('PCD2', 'PC Dual Core', 499, 22, 475, 'PC', NULL);
INSERT INTO E_PRODUCT VALUES ('PCL4', 'Laptop PC', 599, 9, 225, 'PC', NULL);
INSERT INTO E_PRODUCT VALUES ('PCQ5', 'PC Quad Core', 699, 25, 41, 'PC', NULL);
INSERT INTO E_PRODUCT VALUES ('RAM5', '512 Meg RAM Chip', 49.95, 0.25, 625, 'STO', 'No');
INSERT INTO E_PRODUCT VALUES ('RAM9', '1GB RAM Chip', 109.95, 0.3, 513, 'STO', 'No');
INSERT INTO E_PRODUCT VALUES ('VCD2', 'Video Card', 59.95, 1.25, 1210, 'IO', 'No');
```

I am using Oracle Express Edition 10g and using the web interface to execute these instructions.

If I insert them one by one, they work OK but if I enter them all at once and try to execute I get the following error.

```
ORA-00911: invalid character
```

How I can fix this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you want to put the whole thing in an anonymous PL/SQL block and run that, i.e.

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO E_PRODUCT VALUES ('PCD2', 'PC Dual Core', 499, 22, 475, 'PC', NULL);
  INSERT INTO E_PRODUCT VALUES ('PCL4', 'Laptop PC', 599, 9, 225, 'PC', NULL);
  INSERT INTO E_PRODUCT VALUES ('PCQ5', 'PC Quad Core', 699, 25, 41, 'PC', NULL);
  INSERT INTO E_PRODUCT VALUES ('RAM5', '512 Meg RAM Chip', 49.95, 0.25, 625, 'STO', 'No');
  INSERT INTO E_PRODUCT VALUES ('RAM9', '1GB RAM Chip', 109.95, 0.3, 513, 'STO', 'No');
  INSERT INTO E_PRODUCT VALUES ('VCD2', 'Video Card', 59.95, 1.25, 1210, 'IO', 'No');
END;
```

Depending on the tool (SQL*Plus, TOAD, iSQL*Plus, SQL Developer, and the APEX query tool may have slightly different syntax requirements), you could also add a '/' character after each INSERT statement

```
  INSERT INTO E_PRODUCT VALUES ('PCD2', 'PC Dual Core', 499, 22, 475, 'PC', NULL);
  /
  INSERT INTO E_PRODUCT VALUES ('PCL4', 'Laptop PC', 599, 9, 225, 'PC', NULL);
  /
  INSERT INTO E_PRODUCT VALUES ('PCQ5', 'PC Quad Core', 699, 25, 41, 'PC', NULL);
  /
  INSERT INTO E_PRODUCT VALUES ('RAM5', '512 Meg RAM Chip', 49.95, 0.25, 625, 'STO', 'No');
  /
  INSERT INTO E_PRODUCT VALUES ('RAM9', '1GB RAM Chip', 109.95, 0.3, 513, 'STO', 'No');
  /
  INSERT INTO E_PRODUCT VALUES ('VCD2', 'Video Card', 59.95, 1.25, 1210, 'IO', 'No');
  /
```

Comment: This answer is a little bit strange. Your code example is an anonymous  *PL/SQL* block. You **cannot** append a '/' or replace the ';' by a '/' after each INSERT statement. This will raise a syntax error. The block as a whole will be sent to the server. If you use `sqlplus` you have to append a '/' to this block so that it will be sent to the server. The second example is a list of sql statements that can be sent to the server one by one by he client. But sqlplus will send each statement two times: first after ';' and again after the '/'.

Comment: @miracle173 - I'm presenting two options.  The first (recommended) approach is to put everything in an anonymous PL/SQL block.  The second is to leave it a series of SQL statements and add a separator.  As I say in my answer, whether a separator is needed will depend on the front-end tool.  Since the original poster didn't specify that, given the error, I inferred that the tool (or the command being used in the tool) required the separator.

Comment: You should not use `;` **and** `/` in SQL*Plus - especially not for DML statements. `/` executes the last statement in the buffer, so each `INSERT` statement will actually be run twice

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but maybe helpful nevertheless:

The dreaded XE web interface (APEX) does not support running multiple statements or a complete script.

You need to use a different tool (e.g. SQL Developer) or run one statement at a time.